# JS - Cant check if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a web page with various options that can be enabled/disabled.

However, it seems that those options are always enabled, regardless of whether the relevant check boxes are selected or not.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check() {
                var options = "";
                if (document.form1.nocase.value) {
                    options = "1";
                }
                if (document.form1.ck2.value) {
                    options = options + "2";
                }
                alert (options);
            }
        </script>
        <form name="form1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="nocase">option 1
            <input type="checkbox" name="ck2">option 2
            <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="check();">
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I really am having problems understanding where the fault lies. Can anyone point it out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change `document.form1.nocase.value` to `document.form1.nocase.checked` in `if` condition, and the same for `document.form1.global.value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `checked` property and not the `value` property of your input fields:

```
if (document.form1.nocase.checked) {
    //code here
}
```

The `value` attribute is string value that is sent to the server for every checked checkbox and you can specify its value in the html tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="nocase" value="nocase">
```

The `checked` property gives you the desired boolean that shows whether or not the checkbox is checked.